# Drupal 7 how to write a clean url link in Panels, or Content Node

Tags: drupal, hyperlink, drupal-7, clean-urls, drupal-panels

I have enabled clean URLS and it is working fine. 
How ever I have a Panel page with link. the link goes somethinglike this.

```
<a href="?q=PageName">
```

Now, Lets say I am on that Panel page(i would think the same thing would happen on any other custom content pages) and let's call it PanelPage and I press the link, The URL end up being, PanelPage?q=PageName (The whole URL = localhost/SiteName/PanelPage?q=PageName).

My Question is, Is there a way to write that link, so that It coume out as Clean URL? SiteName/PageName ?

Please help. 
Thanks

Comment: Drupal Does it automatically. You do not have to specify clear or un-clean URLs in your links.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`l($text, $path, array $options = array())`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) to generate links.

Comment: I am sorry, I am really new to PHP, can you posibly explain the code? Like I'm 5 :D. How would I rewrite the Link example that I have used?

Answer (score 0):

In drupal 7, after logged in as admin go to following path "**Configuration » Search and metadata » URL aliases**".

There you can set 'Alias Path' for 'Existing Path'. Add an Alias path for your panel page.

For EX:

**Existing system path** : http://www.example.com/PanelPage?q=PageName
**Path alias** : http://www.example.com/custom_name.html